# How to prevent SWF read from memory?

Tags: memory, flash, dump

I'm able now to read an encrypted SWF from a resource to a stream, decrypt the file and load it directly into memory.

But unfortunately there are tools to scan memory and list/view/dump your pure SFW file used by the Flash Player. One such a tool is SFW Vampire.

Even fake SWF signatures doesn't seem to be safe.
There is one tool - SWFkit - who hides all the stuff, but that no longer exists and I use the F-In-Box component with Delphi 7.

**Is there a way to hide/prevent SWF files reading from memory** by fooling such tools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aren`t there any READ_WRITE ACCESS parameters at memory so only your program that reserves the memory can read and write to it ?

I am not an expert in this languages so here is a link if it helps :
http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/

Comment: this is not an answer to OP's post. If you have a question please ask one in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the flash file headers and some other parts after it's loaded to the memory. This is to prevent those tools from recognizing the files in memory. In addition, if it can dump to file, it should be a broken file.